# How to install fonts in Azure Linux Function?

Tags: azure, fonts, azure-functions, multilingual, azure-linux

As I need to display different languages on a webpage (i.e. have multiple languages in text field then use PuppeteerSharp to print as PDF), how to install fonts in Azure Linux Function?

Answer (score 0):

How to install fonts in Azure Linux Function

Inject html and replace the font from CDN

combine [HTML](https://www.puppeteersharp.com/api/index.html#inject-html) code and [CDN](https://github.com/hardkoded/puppeteer-sharp/issues/1510#issuecomment-766180826) code

```
using(var page = await Browser.NewPageAsync())
{
    await page.SetContentAsync("<div>My Receipt</div>");
    var result = await page.GetContentAsync();
    await page.PdfAsync(outputFile);
    SaveHtmlToDB(result);
}
```

```
 html = html.Replace("https://fonts.googleapis.com", "http://fonts.googleapis.com");
```